# imap_status reading two mailboxes at once

Tags: php, imap

is it possible two get the number of messages and the number of the unseen messages, from two mailboxes, in only one `imap_status()` request?

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

No, the STATUS command in IMAP takes one mailbox, and a set of query items.

Answer (score 0):

The `STATUS` command can, however, be executed in parallel. If your IMAP library doesn't support asynchronous command execution, get a better one.

Answer (score 0):

Make a php loop. If you have 3 mailboxes with different account. So make it a loop to fetch the status one by one.